# allow only alphabets for a UITextField

Tags: ios

I am creating a text field.

But the text field should contain only alphabets no numerics. How to do that in ios without checking ASCII values?

Answer (score 2):

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{
    BOOL canEdit=NO;
    NSCharacterSet *myCharSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"];
    for (int i = 0; i < [string length]; i++)
    {
        unichar c = [string characterAtIndex:i];
        if (![myCharSet characterIsMember:c])
        {
            canEdit=NO;
        }
        else
        {
            canEdit=YES;
        }
    }
    return canEdit;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All the above answers tell us how to allow only Alphabets, How about if the user presses BackSpace?
Here is my Solution:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    const char * _char = [string cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    int isBackSpace = strcmp(_char, "\b");

    if (isBackSpace == -8) {
        NSLog(@"Backspace was pressed");
        return YES;
    }

    BOOL canEdit=NO;
    NSCharacterSet *myCharSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz or all Character set you like!!!"];
    for (int i = 0; i < [string length]; i++)
    {
        unichar c = [string characterAtIndex:i];
        if (![myCharSet characterIsMember:c])
        {
            canEdit=NO;
        }
        else
        {
            canEdit=YES;
        }
    }
 return canEdit;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the delegate method `shouldChangeTextInRange` - it's called automatically by the system each time the text changes. In this method you need to vet the input in the textField like so.

In order for this method to be called you need to declare that your class implements the protocol in your class .h file (i.e.`@interface MyClass : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>`) and also set the text field’s delegate to the instance of your class.

```
-(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{

   NSCharacterSet *nonNumberSet = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"] invertedSet];

   NSString *trimmedReplacement =
        [[ text  componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:nonNumberSet]
         componentsJoinedByString:@""];

   return ([text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:nonNumberSet].length > 0); 

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code snippet... But I dint find any such delegate method in UITextFieldDelegate.

Comment: this doesn't allow backspace character… :(

Answer (score 0):

I originally got the code from one of the answers in this question, but modified it when backspace and space was not being allowed. The following block of code allows only alphabets, space and backspace. Numbers and special characters from the default ios keyboard are ignored.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{
    if ([string isEqualToString:@""]) {
        NSString *originalString = textField.text;
        NSInteger newLength = [textField.text length];
        if (originalString.length > newLength)
            myTextfield.text = [originalString substringToIndex:newLength];
        return YES;
    }
    else{
        BOOL canEdit=NO;
        NSCharacterSet *myCharSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"1234567890-/:;()&@\".,?!'[]{}#%^*+=_\\|~<>$£₹€•"];
        for (int i = 0; i < [string length]; i++)
        {
            unichar c = [string characterAtIndex:i];
            if ([myCharSet characterIsMember:c])
            {
                canEdit=NO;
            }
            else
            {
                canEdit=YES;
            }
        }
        return canEdit;
    }
}
```